# HY000 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

So, I saw that there is a lot of questions about this problem, but i couldn't find any solution. I try in PHP to connecto to my database on hosting server but I get this:
**[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away**

The code of PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('database_addres', 'user', '', "database_name");

?>
```

I don't make some query calls or something like that. I tried to connect by PDO and `mysql_connect()`, but there is the same error.
`connect_timeout` is set to 10, `wait_timeout` to 200, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 536870912. So everything seems to be ok. Do I miss something?

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli('Host_address', 'user', 'pass', "database_name"); try hostname

Comment: yup, I'm using host address, I rather thing, that i cannot connect, becouse of some sort of bad configuration of mysql server.

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
try this..

Comment: nothing changed, i get: "Failed to connect to MySQL: MySQL server has gone away"

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't remember but probably the cause of the problem was using wrong address to database.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL server has gone away (error 2006) has two main causes and solutions:
Server timed out and closed the connection. To fix, check that **wait_timeout** mysql variable in your my.cnf configuration file is large enough.

Server dropped an incorrect or too large packet. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. To fix, you can increase the maximal packet size limit **max_allowed_packet** in my.cnf file, eg. set **max_allowed_packet** = 128M, then restart your MySQL server: **sudo /etc/init.d/mysql** restart